# Pointer, string and overflow error

Tags: c++, string, overflow

I am new to C++ and programming and I'm writing a small program as part of an assignment and got it to work, but I am trying to make the code run faster, so i'm trying to get my vector to store a pointer to a struct.

The struct is

```
struct info {
    string all;
    string word;
}
```

And what I did was, trying to assign the string 'all' a value;

```
info* v;
v->all = str;
```

And str is defined as

```
string str = "Hello";
```

The error that I got upon running GDB was;

```
File "/usr/share/gdb/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.py", line 469, in to_string
return self.val['_M_dataplus']['_M_p'].string (encoding, length = len)
OverflowError: signed integer is greater than maximum
```

Any clue as to what might be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`v` is not initialized.

Make it

```
info* v = new info; 
v->all = str;
```

But you really should show more code. It's not clear, what you are trying to do and how storing a pointer will make the code run faster.

Comment: And remember about `delete v`, when it is no longer needed.

Comment: Thank you for the response. In making v a pointer to info I deliberately added a '*' and forgot about the 'new'...

Answer (score 1):

`info* v;` just *defines pointer which is pointing to some random memory location* , to use it you need to allocate a memory for `info` and make this pointer point to this memory. You can do it using `new` like this: `info* v = new info();`. Note that you need to release the memory yourself by doing `delete v;`.

Answer (score 0):

You cant use a memory location unless its allocated. `info *v` creates only a pointer to the memory location and at present its pointing to junk. you have to allocate memory to it using `new`. after `new` ing you acn use the `str` to assign value to it.

or you can also use static memory allocation